# Problem syncing gradle: Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle because no repositories are defined

Tags: android, flutter, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-ndk

Trying to run a flutter android build and getting the following error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'example_app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle because no repositories are defined.
> > Required by:
> > project :
> > Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3 because no repositories are
> > defined.
> > Required by:
> > project :

Am using [flutter_unity_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget). Have tried solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218626/cannot-resolve-external-dependency-for-gradle) to no avail. The error happens when trying to sync the gradle files in android studio. Any idea?

Have added the Unity NDK location to my android/gradle.properties file:

```
ndk.dir=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.24f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
unityStreamingAssets=.unity3d, google-services-desktop.json, google-services.json, GoogleService-Info.plist
ndk.dir=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.24f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  latest build gradle ffile
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'